# Generalization of a result on finite Galois extensions to infinite case.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

It is well known that if $L/K$ is a finite abelian extension, $\frak p$  a prime of $K$ and $\frak P$ a prime of $L$ above  $\frak p,$ then $L^I /K$ is the maximal subextension of $L/K$ in which $\frak p$ is unramified, where $I=I(\frak P/p)$ is the inirtia group of $\frak p.$

> **Is it always the case for infinite abelian extensions** ?

Some hints please I am sur that is true but I don't have an idea to starting,
Thanks very much for any help.